# Realm Swift - Filter on first element of a relationship

Tags: swift, filter, realm

I have 2 realm object A and B linked with a relationship :

```
class A: Object {
    let Bs = List<B>()
}

class B: Object {
    dynamic var Id:Int = 0
}
```

So now, I need to get all A objects where the first Bs has the Id = 1.
If I use this line of code :

```
realm.objects(A).filter("ANY Bs.Id = 1")
```

I get all A objects, where one of the Bs has the Id = 1. But in my case, I need to check only the first Bs. Is it possible to do that in Realm ? Is there something like :

```
realm.objects(A).filter("FIRST Bs.Id = 1")
or
realm.objects(A).filter("TOP Bs.Id = 1")
```

Thank you for your help ! :)

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
realm.objects(A).filter("ANY Bs.Id = 1").first
```

Do you have any other conditions?